# What makes Internet Explorer not display the "Always ask before opening this type of file" option for downloaded files?

Tags: windows-7, download, internet-explorer-11

**Problem**

Users want that a certain type of file downloaded from an intranet URL with Internet Explorer is automatically opened without asking whether the file should be saved or opened.

To do that, one would normally open Internet Explorer's Downloads, right click on the downloaded file and uncheck the "Always ask before opening this type of file" option.

While this works for some users, it does not work for others because Internet Explorer does not display this option.

**More information**

This is Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 in an AD domain.

Internet Explorer shows that the URL the file is downloaded from belongs to the intranet zone.

The type of file is associated with a company internal application which is opened correctly if the user tells Internet Explorer to open the file.

For those users who see and unchecked the "Always ask before opening this type of file" option, this setting is stored in the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\AttachmentExecute\{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` (one value per file type).

Copying these registry entries from one user to another does not help; even if present, Internet Explorer continues to ask whether to save or open this type of file.

However, if an affected user logs in on a different computer where he has never logged in before and thus did not have a local profile yet, he does see the "Always ask before opening this type of file" option, and if he unchecks it, the file is then automatically opened.

The same goes for an unaffected user logging in on the computer of the affected user (again without a previously existing local profile).

The fact that it works when the same user logs in on a different computer or another user logs in on the same computer suggests that it is someting in the local profile.

We have reviewed items such as security settings and group policies that we came across when researching the problem, but could not find anything that explains the observed behaviour.

**Question**

What makes Internet Explorer not display the "Always ask before opening this type of file" option for downloaded files?

Others have had this problem before (see comments [here](https://jwcooney.com/2014/03/31/remove-internet-explorer-open-or-save-popup/)), has anyone ever found a solution?

Does anyone have any idea what else to review/compare/test to find out the cause?